# I need Help with a riddle?

Tags: riddle

Riddle?

```
While secrets are best kept - 
mine is shared for all - 
hear me and do despair - 
but my words are not spoken
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its:

> Silence

While secrets are best kept -

> Secrets are best kept silent

mine is shared for all -

> The secret to silence is available to anyone (i.e. keep your mouth shut)

hear me and do despair -

> Hearing silence can cause despair

but my words are not spoken

> In silence, words are not spoken

Answer (score 11):

You are

> S.O.S.

While secrets are best kept -

> S.O.S. is a code and some codes are secret codes

mine is shared for all -

> All know what S.O.S. means, it's not secret

hear me and do despair -

> If you hear ...---... then you know there's a problem

but my words are not spoken

> The words Save Our Ships are abbreviated and not pronounced

I need Help with a riddle

> "I need Help" is the meaning of S.O.S.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> A Share / Trade Exchange display ( showing the Ups and Downs of market)

While secrets are best kept - mine is shared for all -

> Performance of a share market is telecasted as well !

hear me and do despair -

> In a bearish market, these kind of expressions are normal !!

but my words are not spoken

> The words (and assoiciated indices / values) are not spoken, usually, they are displayed on screens.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've come up with another possibility

Is it

> Grades? (School, College, Uni, etc)

While secrets are best kept -

> You often wish to keep your grades secret to avoid disgrace amongst friends and family.

mine is shared for all -

> No matter what you wish for they are always published on report cards, class tables, etc.

hear me and do despair -

> Most people who get bad grades do despair for the consequences.

but my words are not spoken

> Again they are usually published onto paper so they can be read rather than being spoken.